# Why casting to IEnumerable<T> when passing list to another list as constructor?

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

I saw the following code:

```
this.list = new List<GameObject>((IEnumerable<GameObject>) this.someVar.otherList);
```

where `otherList` is declared as follows:

```
public List<GameObject> otherList = new List<GameObject>();
```

Why do we need to cast the list passed to the constructor to `(IEnumerable<GameObject>)`, what exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do that, ever. The constructor takes `IEnumerable<T>`, and that's what it gets - regardless of whether you do the cast explicitly (`new List<GameObject>((IEnumerable<GameObject>)otherList)` or implicitly (`new List<GameObject>(otherList)`).

The only reason where you'd want to be explicit is if there were multiple overloads, e.g. if there was an overload that took `List<GameObject>` and you specifically wanted to use th `IEnumerable<GameObject>` overload for some reason.

If the code was generated, it would be understandable to have the explicit cast. If it was handwritten, someone needs to review their knowledge of C# :)

Comment: Thanks, that code is from a decompiler, so that could explain that weird line.

Comment: @aa Yeah, it's perfectly fine as a result from a decompiler - the IL code of course does a cast, it's just C# where it doesn't matter (that is, in C#, both an explicit and implicit cast will have the same result).

Answer (score 1):

This was not necessary. I don't know *why* it was done, but the List constructor takes `IEnumerable` objects. A list is *already* an `IEnumerable` object, so the cast was redundant.